# Making a thread which cancels a InputStream.read() call if 'x' time has passed

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, android-asynctask, nio

I currently have a working I/O stream from Android's [BluetoothChat Example](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html), but have run into problems. My application connects via bluetooth to a bluetooth module, which in turn sends a signal to a device the module is physically attached to.

My program calls `read()` on an input stream, and if there is data being sent the program executes smoothly with no problems. However, the way the stream is implemented there is no protection against an interrupted connection. If the module is physically removed from the device, or if the device doesn't send any signals back, my code simply sits and waits at the `InputStream.read()` call.

My `read()` call looks like this:

```
try {
    Log.i( "1) I/O", "available bits: " + mmInStream.available() );
    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);
    Log.i( "2) I/O", "available bits: " + mmInStream.available() );
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG,  "Catch Statement" );
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString( TOAST, "Device has disconnected from the Bluetooth Module." );
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected a", e);
    connectionLost();

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    BluetoothService.this.start();
    //break;
}
```

When my program acts correctly, both of the `Log` calls in the `try` block return values of `0` for `mmInStream.available()`. When the input stream is interrupted, the initial `Log` call returns a `0`, and the second is never called. My program then ends up crashing before the `catch` block is every reached.

I have been looking for several days now to fix this, and have found numerous solutions, but they have either not worked, or I do not understand them.

1) Using a scanner for the InputStream is shown below. This provided no help and also timed out while reading.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(mmInStream));
scan.useDelimiter( "[\\r\\n]+" );
String readIn;

try {
    readIn = scan.next();
    scan = null;
    tempB = readIn.getBytes( Charset.forName( "US-ASCII" ) );
    append = "\r\n".getBytes( Charset.forName( "US-ASCII" ) );
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        if( i == length - 1 ) {
            buffer[i] = append[1];
        } else if ( i == length - 2 ) {
            buffer[i] = append[0];
        } else {
            buffer[i] = tempB[i];
        }
    }
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG,  "Catch Statement" );
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString( TOAST, "Device has disconnected from the Bluetooth Module." );
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected a", e);
                connectionLost();

                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start();
                //break;
            }
```

2) I have tried running a Thread which would cancel the `read` call after X amount of time, but it would not work correctly:

```
public void run(int length) throws IOException {
    buffer = new byte[1024];
    length1 = length;
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read( buffer, 0, length1 );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    synchronized (myThread) {
        myThread.start();
        try {
            myThread.wait(500);
            if(myThread.isAlive()) {
                mmInStream.close();
                Log.i( "InStream", "Timeout exceeded!");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   try {
        myThread.run();
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
   } catch (IOException e) {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString( TOAST, "Device has disconnected from the Bluetooth Module." );
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            connectionLost();
            BluetoothService.this.start();
   }
```

After those two options didn't work, I have been trying to look into `Java NIO` or `AsyncTask`, but all of this seems like way too much stuff to add for recognizing an I/O timeout. I have also seen that some `Sockets` support a timeout feature using `.setSoTimeout()`, however this is a `BluetoothSocket` and from what I've found they do not support this feature.

Since there is no `I/O` class which supports a `read()` method that takes a timeout length as a parameter, or timeout at all, it seems to me that adding a Thread would be the simplest implementation. Is this wrong? Any information on what I'm doing wrong with the above methods, or how to incorporate `Java NIO`/`AsyncTask` would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the new thread code I tried, I am currently changing it to what the given answer shows and trying that. I will post that if it doesn't work after.

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read( buffer, 0, length1 );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        synchronized (myThread) {
            try {
                myThread.wait(6000);
                Log.i( "InStream", "After wait" );
                if(myThread.isAlive()) {
                    Log.i( "InStream", "Timeout exceeded2!");
                    myThread.interrupt();
                    Log.i( "InStream", "Timeout exceeded!");
                } else {
                    myThread.interrupt();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i( "InStream", "Exception Caught" );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

EDIT 2:

I have tried the answer `Dheerej` has given below. I get an `IllegalMonitorStateException` on the `wait()` function call. I tried as it was shown in the answer, then also tried `myThread.wait()` instead of `Thread.currentThread.wait()`. I'm assuming this exception is being thrown because this is `myThread` object is being created and ran within another thread. Anyway, the code below is almost identical to `Dheerej's` answer.

```
        int length1 = length;
            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    try {
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                                .sendToTarget();
                }
            });

            myThread.start();
            try {
                //Thread.currentThread().wait(500);
                myThread.wait( 1000 );              // Line 533
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.i(TAG,  "Catch Statement" );
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString( TOAST, "Device has disconnected from the Bluetooth Module." );
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected a", e);
                connectionLost();

                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start();
            }

            if (myThread.isAlive()) {
                mmInStream.close(); // Alternatively try: myThread.interrupt()
            }
```

This is the resulting LogCat. The error says it starts in line 533, which is the `wait()` call above:

```
12-28 17:44:18.765: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(3242): blz20_wrp_poll: return 1
12-28 17:44:18.765: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(3242): blz20_wrp_write: wrote 3 bytes out of 3 on fd 62
12-28 17:44:18.769: W/NATIVE CODE(3242): -4) baud9600=1, goodbaud=1
12-28 17:44:18.769: D/AndroidRuntime(3242): Shutting down VM
12-28 17:44:18.769: W/dalvikvm(3242): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at my.eti.commander.BluetoothService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothService.java:533)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at my.eti.commander.BluetoothService.read(BluetoothService.java:326)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at my.eti.commander.BluetoothService.changeitJava(BluetoothService.java:669)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.changeItJavaWrapper(RelayAPIModel.java:490)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.InitRelayJava(Native Method)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at my.eti.commander.MainMenu$1.handleMessage(MainMenu.java:547)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-28 17:44:18.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 17:44:18.781: D/BLZ20_ASOCKWRP(3242): asocket_read
12-28 17:44:18.781: I/BLZ20_WRAPPER(3242): blz20_wrp_poll: nfds 2, timeout -1 ms
12-28 17:44:18.890: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(3242): blz20_wrp_poll: transp poll : (fd 62) returned r_ev [POLLIN ] (0x1)
12-28 17:44:18.890: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(3242): blz20_wrp_poll: return 1
12-28 17:44:18.890: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(3242): blz20_wrp_read: read 5 bytes out of 5 on fd 62
```

Comment: Just a wild guess after working with the BluetoothChat example for the past weeks: I think that the inputstream has an `isAvailable` method. Maybe a while-loop will do it all?

Comment: Thanks, but as I show in my first code block, everytime I call `.isAvailable()` a `0` is returned. Even when my code executes correctly and receives info, a `0` is returned.

Comment: Why are you calling `myThread.run()` explicitly after calling `myThread.start()`?? Try calling `myThread.interrupt()` instead of `mmInStream.close()` after the wait.

Comment: I don't call `run()` after `start()`. I call `run()` and then within the `synchronized` call call `start()`. That could very well be wrong, but its different than what you had read it as. I will try this soon. Thanks

Comment: Gave that a shot. It's not working. It simply loops through myThread over and over never entering the `if(myThread.isAlive())` function call.

Comment: Thread implementation is not correct. You should wait in run() method. Currently, once run() ends, thread life is over. So isAlive() never returns true. Do not call run() explicitly as suggested above and if changes are made do share.  As for original code, try using isAvailable() and then available() as suggested by comment 1. Again do share any changes. As for not reaching catch block, only possibility is Error() is thrown not an Exception(). Try catching Throwable() just for debug. If that works do re-factor as catching Exception or Error is not good choice.

Comment: @VishalKumar I updated my code a bit and posted it.

Comment: in your second code block, what is the variable length and where did you initialize it?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I'm not sure which code block you are talking about, but length is passed as a parameter to my `run()` function. All of the code shown above is within the `run()` function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this first:

```
try {
    int available = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        int available = mmInStream.available();
        if (available > 0) { break; }
        Thread.sleep(1);
        // here you can optionally check elapsed time, and time out
    }

    Log.i( "1) I/O", "available bits: " + available );
    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);
    Log.i( "2) I/O", "available bits: " + mmInStream.available() );
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

In your original code, you call `available()` before `read()`, typically there is no data waiting to be read.  Then you call `read()`, which blocks and waits for data, then reads all of it.  Then you call `available()` again and once again there is no data, because it has all been read :)   Better: sleep until `available()` returns nonzero, then read.  However, this may not work, because `available()` is *always* allowed to return 0 (even if data is actually available).

If the above doesn't work, try the technique from this question: [Is it possible to read from a InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout)

```
Callable<Integer> readTask = new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}

try {
    Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(readTask);
    bytes = future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // deal with timeout in the read call
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Lastly, the `BluetoothSocket` docs say that you can close the socket from any thread and that takes effect immediately.  So you could simply have a watchdog thread and if the read call hasn't succeeded call `close()` on the socket which would cause the blocked `read()` to return with an error.  This was what Dheeraj suggested above, but you only need to call `close()` when the other thread is stuck (due to network error/connection lost/etc): otherwise just check on its progress once in a while but don't close as long as your read hasn't taken too long.

It certainly looks like the lack of timeouts (and the impossibility of interrupting a blocked read() from the outside) has been a major ongoing pain point in Java for a *long* time.

See also:

[Is it possible to read from a InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout) (uses `Callable`/`Future`)

[Can I set a timeout for a InputStream's read() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638283/can-i-set-a-timeout-for-a-inputstreams-read-function) (uses `Socket.setSoTimeout()`)

[How to kill a BufferedInputStream .read() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041490/how-to-kill-a-bufferedinputstream-read-call?lq=1) (uses `InterruptibleChannel`)

[How to stop a thread waiting in a blocking read operation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182491/how-to-stop-a-thread-waiting-in-a-blocking-read-operation-in-java?lq=1)

Comment: Sorry, I've been away these past few days giving it a read now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first implementation you gave me works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, if you don't mind me asking. I got a bit confused with this, i tried out the first implementation and it just staying in the while loop like forever. It did not proceed to the `bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);` part

Comment: @IssacZH.: Some InputStream implementations always return 0 from the available() call.  It is also possible the stream didn't have any data available to read.  Did you try reading it regardless of the returned value?  What kind of stream are you using?  Try something simple like ByteArrayInputStream or FileInputStream.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code which expands on my comment above:

```
public void run(final int length) {
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
        }
    });

    myThread.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (myThread.isAlive()) {
        mmInStream.close(); // Alternatively try: myThread.interrupt()
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code and edited my question with the results. I tried using what you had written, then I tried `myThread.interrupt()` instead of `mmInstream.close()`, then switched `Thread.currentThread().wait(500)` to `myThread.wait(500)`. I then switched back to `mmInStream.close` but the error is raised in the line containing the `wait()` call. Also, I'm not sure if it matters, but this thread is being instantiated and run within another thread.

Comment: @JuiCe used `sleep()` instead. I must've been sleep()ing not to notice this :-)

Comment: Alright, so it works, kind of. I can go through my first set of read/write commands. But after that, it gets stuck deep in my code. Is there something else I can do other than `mmInStream.close()` since I'll be using it again later?

Comment: @JuiCe No. You may have to consider synchronizing the threads to avoid race conditions. Post another question with the relevant code if you get stuck.

Comment: Keep the `InputStream` object as local as possible. Before using it later check if it was closed.